# Procedure not creating the number

Tags: c#, sql

I need to use this procedure and when I insert the new employee I need to create EmpID in database like A1001,A1002...

But when I using this procedure it shows error to pass EmpID.

**Sql Procedure:**

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[addemp]
    @EmpId nvarchar(10),
    @EmpName nvarchar(50),
    @EmpAddress nvarchar(50)
as 
begin
    declare @Totalcount int
    declare @Count nvarchar(10)

    select @Totalcount=(select COUNT(EmpID) from NewEmp)

    if @Totalcount is null
    set @Count='A'+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),1001)
    else
    set @Count='A'+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),1001+(@Totalcount))

    insert into NewEmp([EmpId],[EmpName],[EmpAddress]) values (@Count,@EmpName,@EmpAddress)
end
```

**C# Code:-**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Emp"].ConnectionString;
     SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(cs);
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("addemp", scon);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     scon.Open();
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName",TextBox2.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpAddress", TextBox3.Text);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   
}
```

Comment: Tag the dbms product used. (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: "Procedure or function 'addemp' expects parameter '@EmpId', which was not supplied.

Comment: `@TotalCount` is never null but 0 if there are no rows. Note that if `EmpID` can be `null` you wouldn't count these null-rows. Instead you should use `COUNT(*)`

Comment: are you able to execute your procedure in sql studio?

Comment: @Shakir Ahamed - I accepted your edit as it contained some improvements - but you had added code in that was not in the original question - and that causes the very issue that they are asking about.

Comment: Note if some day a row will be deleted from `NewEmp`, you'll get doubles due to `select @Totalcount=(select COUNT(EmpID) from NewEmp)`.

Comment: Be cautious if your EmpId have to be unique, and I guess it should. In case you delete any records you might have duplicate EmpId generated. Imagine you have 10 entries and A10 id for the last, delete one, and create a new one you'd get A10 generated again.  This code might be dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not going to use declared parameter @EmpId in SP, so please **remove @EmpId** parameter from SP

**OR**

Set default value : @EmpId=''

```
create procedure [dbo].[addemp]
    @EmpId nvarchar(10)='',
    @EmpName nvarchar(50)='',
    @EmpAddress nvarchar(50)=''
as 
begin
declare @Totalcount int
declare @Count nvarchar(10)

select @Totalcount=(select COUNT(EmpID) from NewEmp)

if @Totalcount is null
set @Count='A'+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),1001)
else
set @Count='A'+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),1001+(@Totalcount))

insert into NewEmp([EmpId],[EmpName],[EmpAddress]) values (@Count,@EmpName,@EmpAddress)
end
```

Comment: if i am remove EmpID from procedure then its give error

Comment: Error from Sql side Or C# side?

Comment: If you set default value to '' it will not give your error

Comment: when i altering the procedure as remove with empID also shows procedure expects the EmpID parameter

Comment: Better go with second option, also in first option it should not throw such error are you use linq?

Comment: when i remove the EmpID parameter from sql then it not creating the EmpID on new row insertion

Comment: What is "1001" in your SP?

Comment: Try {SELECT @Count,@EmpName,@EmpAddress} begore insert query and check what value each parameter show

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a stored procedure. SQL Server has the option of *computed columns* which you can use to your advantage.

This will also take care of duplicate `EmpId` problem that may arise when a row is deleted from the table.

Just declare your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE NewEmp 
(
    ID BIGINT Identity(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [EmpId] AS 'A' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 1000 + ID),
    [EmpName] VARCHAR(255),
    [EmpAddress] VARCHAR(255)

    -- add more columns here if required...

)
```

Now you don't need to use any stored procedure etc. to generate your EmpId; it will be computed automatically.

You can use simple insert statement to add records to the table.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO NewEmp ([EmpName], [EmpAddress]) 
VALUES ('test name1', 'test address1')

INSERT INTO NewEmp ([EmpName], [EmpAddress]) 
VALUES ('test name2', 'test address2')

INSERT INTO NewEmp ([EmpName], [EmpAddress]) 
VALUES ('test name3', 'test address3')

INSERT INTO NewEmp ([EmpName], [EmpAddress]) 
VALUES ('test name4', 'test address4')

INSERT INTO NewEmp ([EmpName], [EmpAddress]) 
VALUES ('test name5', 'test address5')

INSERT INTO NewEmp ([EmpName], [EmpAddress]) 
VALUES ('test name6', 'test address6')

SELECT * FROM NewEmp
```

Output:

```
|----| ----- | ---------- |---------------|
| ID | EmpId |    EmpName | EmpAddress    |
|----| ----- | ---------- |---------------|
| 1  | A1001 | test name1 | test address1 |
| 2  | A1002 | test name2 | test address2 |
| 3  | A1003 | test name3 | test address3 |
| 4  | A1004 | test name4 | test address4 |
| 5  | A1005 | test name5 | test address5 |
| 6  | A1006 | test name6 | test address6 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing EmpId for the procedure, ether give the id or change procedure so that EmpId dosen't need to be given

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table NewEmp
(
EmpId nvarchar(10),
EmpName Varchar(255),
EmpAddress Varchar(255),
MaxID INt
)  

Declare @EmpId NVARCHAR(10),
        @EmpName NVARCHAR(50),
        @EmpAddress NVARCHAR(50),
        @Count NVARCHAR(10),
        @MaxID INT

SET @EmpId = NULL
SET @EmpName ='Alfaiz' 
SET @EmpAddress ='Worli'

    SELECT @MaxID=Max(MaxID) FROM NewEmp 

    IF @MaxID Is NUll 
         SET @MaxID=1
    Else 
        Select @MaxID = Max(MaxID) + 1 FROM NewEmp 

    IF @MaxID is null 
        SET @Count='A'+Convert(VARCHAR(25),1001)
    ELSE 
        SET @Count='A'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),1000 + @MaxID)

INSERT INTO NewEmp
    ([EmpId],[EmpName],[EmpAddress],MaxID) 
VALUES 
    (@Count,@EmpName,@EmpAddress,@MaxID)
```

Comment: Check It Out Hope You will Get The Result what you Looking for